# Angular Material Sorting not works properly

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, asynchronous, angular-material

I have a data table with sorting, but the sorting works only if I use the same name in the `matCellDef` and in the template variable. Ex.:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="SS_KEY">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Licenza </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="nome-col"> {{element.SS_KEY}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

But if I use a method I have the data displayed but the sorting is not working (only the first two items are sorted):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="cliente">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cliente </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="nome-col"> {{getCustomerName(element.SS_SC_ID)}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

this is the .ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {    
  this.fetchClienti();
}

fetchClienti() {
  this.clientiApi.getCustomers()
    .subscribe(clienti => {
      this.clienti = clienti;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

getCustomerName(id) {
  let result = '';
  this.clienti.forEach((cliente) => {
    if (cliente['SC_ID'] === id) {
      result = cliente['SC_NOME'];
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

using `async` pipe does not solve the problem

EDIT: here a Stackblitz that shows the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-sort-issue

PS: the undefined error is not logged in my browser, only in stackblitz... by the way the sort is not working

Thanks for help

Comment: can you please add your code to stackblitz & shows us the issue.

Comment: thanks for the answert, here a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-sort-issue

Comment: `displayedColumns` should match properties that are returned by your api.https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Comment: ok, but what if I want to use two times the same field?